# How do I render the bottom edge of a shape at a fixed position?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to present some text in a rounded rectangle at a specific (x, y) coordinate in a parent view.  I can accomplish that like this:

```swift
ZStack {
    ZStack() {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
            .fill(.white)
        Text("Foo")
            .padding(2)
        }
        .fixedSize()
        .position(x: 100, y: 100)
    }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    .background(.blue)
}
```

... which renders the centre of the rounded rectangle at (100, 100).  How can I render the rounded rectangle so the centre of the bottom edge is at (x, y)?

The size of the rounded rectangle isn't known at design time - it adjusts to the size of the text - hence the use of `fixedSize()`.

I've tried using `.frame(alignment: .bottom)`.

Comment: What's the purpose? I just feel you try to do something in wrong way.

Comment: I need to show an annotation on a point on a graph.  I convert from the graph (x, y) values to the view coordinates.  Then I need to show the annotation above the point on the graph.